# AppInsights is only saving telemetry data but not saving logs with a .Net Core web app hosted on an IIS

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-application-insights, appinsights

My `Program` class looks like this

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateWebHostBuilder(args)
            .Build()
            .Run();
    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration((webHostingBuilder, configBuilder) =>
            {
                configBuilder.SetBasePath(webHostingBuilder.HostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath)
                                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{webHostingBuilder.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                                .AddEnvironmentVariables();
            })
        .ConfigureLogging((webHostingBuilder, logging) =>
        {
            logging.ClearProviders();
            logging.AddConsole();
            logging.AddDebug();
            logging.AddApplicationInsights(
                webHostingBuilder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("Logging:ApplicationInsights:InstrumentationKey"));
        })
        .UseStartup<Startup>();
}
```

and on my `Startup` on `ConfigureServices`

```
services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(configuration["Logging:ApplicationInsights:InstrumentationKey"]);
```

And this is my controller class:

```
public class AccountController : BaseController
{
    private ILogger _logger;

    public AccountController(ILogger<AccountController> logger)
    {   ... } 

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(string returnUrl)
    {
        _logger.LogError("SuperError");
    }
}
```

Is there anything else that I need to configure in order to save the logs?
I couldn't see anything here while doing my example

[image]

Comment: not clear about the question, do you mean _logger.LogError("SuperError"); does not work? for example, you cannot see the message SuperError in application insights?

Comment: @IvanYang yes, I can't see it

Comment: do you check it in the Logs -> `traces` table?

Comment: Logs are persisted on the cloud, do you mean Logs tab that I highlighted?

Comment: yes, can you see the message from there?

Comment: as I said, no logs are saved, any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks good. Sometimes it can take a while for logs to show up in `App Insights`. Example configuration that works given a correct `InstrumentationKey`:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/ilogger#im-using-the-standalone-package-microsoftextensionsloggingapplicationinsights-and-enabling-application-insights-provider-by-calling-builderaddapplicationinsightsikey-is-there-an-option-to-get-an-instrumentation-key-from-configuration

Startup.cs

```
services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();
```

appsettings.json

```
"ApplicationInsights": {
  "InstrumentationKey": "putinstrumentationkeyhere"
}
```

WeatherForecastController.cs

```
private readonly ILogger<WeatherForecastController> _logger;

public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger)
{
    _logger = logger;
}

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult<IEnumerable<WeatherForecast>> Get()
{
    _logger.LogInformation("WeatherForecastController Get");
```

Comment: I have the same configuration and I put. Thread.Sleep(3000) on the controller and it didn't work

Comment: @Zinov Do you have a working `InstrumentationKey`? Are you trying this from localhost? Are you allowing connections to Azure in that case?

Comment: I have a working InstrumentationKey and I am trying from localhost first with the visual studio, and with my local IIS